# Call an index controller with parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So basically, I have a setup of restful controller in my route. Now my problem is how can I call the **Index** page if there is a parameter.. it gives me an error of Controller not found

Im trying to call it like this [www.domain.com/sign-up/asdasdasd](http://www.domain.com/sign-up/asdasdasd)

```
Route::controller('sign-up','UserRegisterController');
```

then in my Controller

```
class UserRegisterController extends \BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.unregistered';

    public function getIndex( $unique_code = null )
    {
        $title = 'Register';
        $this->layout->content = View::make( 'pages.unregistred.sign-up', compact('title', 'affiliate_ash'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By registering:

```
Route::controller('sign-up','UserRegisterController');
```

You're telling the routes that every time the url starts with /sign-up/ it should look for corresponding action in `UserRegisterController` in `verbAction` convention.

Suppose you have:

http://domain.com/sign-up/social-signup

Logically it'll be mapped to `UserRegister@getSocialSignup` (GET verb because it is a GET request). And if there is nothing after `/sign-up/` it'll look for `getIndex()` by default.

Now, consider your example:

http://domain.com/sign-up/asdasdasd

By the same logic, it'll try looking for `UserRegister@getAsdasdasd` which most likely you don't have. The problem here is there is no way of telling `Route` that `asdasdasd` is actually a parameter. At least, not with a single `Route` definition.

You'll have to define another route, perhaps after your `Route::controller`

```
Route::controller('sign-up','UserRegisterController');
// If above fail to find correct controller method, check the next line.
Route::get('sign-up/{param}', 'UserRegisterController@getIndex');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parameter in the route `Route::controller('sign-up/{unique_code?}','UserRegisterController');`. The question mark makes it optional.

Full documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Uhm. is it really applicable to a restful controller route? I tried using it and it made all the methods in my controller go wrong

Comment: Should work the exact same, can you give me your error?